# Wrong decimal numeric value with init value (Inputmask JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I have a problem numeric with init value. The init value `2042.09` should be `2.042,09` but it gives `204.209,00`

```
$(".target").inputmask('numeric', {
            radixPoint:",",
            groupSeparator: ".",
            allowMinus: false,
            unmaskAsNumber: true,
            digits: 2,
            removeMaskOnSubmit: true,

            autoUnmask: true,
            digitsOptional: false,
        })
```

- JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0mfjg5t6/7/
- OS: Windows 10
- Browser : Chrome
- Inputmask version : 5.0.5

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/5.x/README_numeric.md#setting-initial-values) says the following about setting initial values:

```
//html
<input name="npt" value="123456,789"/>

//js
Inputmask("decimal", {
    radixPoint: ',',
    inputtype: "text"
}).mask("input");

$("input").val("123456,789");
$("input").val(123456.789); //this doesn't work because jQuery converts the number to a string before passing it along to the Inputmask.

document.getElementsByName("npt")[0].value = "123456,789";
document.getElementsByName("npt")[0].value = 123456.789; //type number
```

i.e. You need to respect the syntax when declaring initial value in HTML or via jQuery's `.val()`.

Comment: I'm using the same field for create and edit. So what should i do if i need in one declaration?

Comment: Can you show me in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0mfjg5t6/7/?

Comment: I've tried to used like the example but it effected to others input